# How to delete file pattern in user profile directory

Tags: batch-file

I would like to create a batch file that will delete all files of `f_*.*` from the following user directory

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\
```

How can I have the batch file step through several user profiles doing this on a particular terminal server?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this in a batch, for all users:

```
for /D %%u in (C:\Users\*) do del "%%u\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\f_*.*"
```

For specific users (1 and 2) you can do:

```
for %%u in (user1 user2) do del "C:\Users\%%u\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\f_*.*"
```

What this command does is loop through the directories retrieved in the brackets `()` and `do` a delete command.

Notes:

- You will need admin permissions of course.
- You will need to handle hidden files or other specific settings of the command.